# UDF (user-defined function) to identify the format pattern for an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

**Problem**:
I have an Excel sheet that have patterns in some cells, indicating the presence of a certain trait.
I need to give a numeric/text code to each cell that has a pattern, other than the "no pattern/white" cell.

[example on how it might look before applying the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ5B2.png)

Since I have no experience with programing VBA functions in Excel (or in general), I have tried to generate an UDF that would simply provide a code when the cell has any pattern. The idea was to have a formula written in the cell, something like: =IntPattern(A1), that would return the code of the pattern for cell A1.

The code that I have tried to implement is the following:

```vb
Function IntPattern(Pattern As Range) 
Application.Volatile 
IntPattern=Interior.Pattern
End Function
```

However, it does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function need to be in a module for it to work.  Right click on your project, add a new module and paste the code below.  Also, I would not use the word Pattern as the variable since pattern is a property.  Try this:

```
Public Function IntPattern(rng As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    IntPattern = rng.Interior.pattern
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The critical line should be

```
IntPattern = Pattern.Interior.Pattern
```

The confusion is of your own making: why did you call the range "Pattern"? It is that range that you want the pattern of. Therefore it must be specified in the instruction.

Call the function from a cell with something like `=IntPattern(A2)` where A2 is the cell from which to read the patter. It can be the cell that contains the formula or any other cell.

If the referenced cell is without patter the return will be `xlNone` = -4142. Therefore your UDF's functionality can be expanded like,

```
Function IntPattern(Pattern As Range)

    With Pattern.Interior
        IntPattern = IIf(.Pattern = xlNone, "No pattern", "Pattern " & .Pattern)
    End With
End Function
```

You can add `Application.Volatile` if you want that functionality.